# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec.getInputStream looses content

Tags: java

Hy i am running a program with

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myprogram.exe");
InputStream inp = p.getInputStream();
while(true) {
        char in = 0;
    if(inp.available()>0) {
        in = (char) inp.read();
        System.out.print(Character.valueOf(in));
    }
}
```

now my problem is this myprogram.exe outputs much debug messages and Java loses some content (wehen i start the same cmd line with cmd.exe i see the expected content)
Is there any thing i can do such as increasing buffersize.
I already checked if the content comes from the ErrorStream.

Comment: How is `inp` initialized in your code? Please [edit] your question to contain all of the relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure the output is not being written to System.err or stderr as you are not reading that stream?  You can use ProcessBuilder to combine the standard output and standard error streams.

Comment: sry missed a line ^^ added it

Comment: Yes like i said i also looked if the content comes from the Error Stream

Comment: You want to get all output from the process, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see all output, because, there are two streams program can write to:

printStream and errorStream

you need to read both in order to have all the text that your program is outputting.

read also the error content from `Java.lang.Process.getErrorStream()`

Comment: Ok i found the problem. First i have to read stderr, if not myprogram.exe is going to wait(I throw it away since the Data i am intrested in come only from stdout) till the stdxxx buffer is read. second i have to read them unblocking means check BufferReader instance.ready and not use readLine.